# Python and boto package for AWS: distributing files on the clusters

Tags: python, caching, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I am currently testing a Python script on an EMR instance with the Boto package.

The script reads each row of a file called fileC, compare their content with the content of the rows in fileAC, and write in a separate file the filtered rows. As I am comparing 2  big files, I created another intermediate filter with a third file called fileA to gain time.

The problem is the following: during my tests on a local machine, the script works fine, filters out more than 200 rows from fileC. But once I try on AWS with Boto package, the script doesn’t filter fileC at all (p=0, no “found” displayed and the same number of rows as fileC). It seems that the 2 files fileA and fileAC are not read. With boto, I used the functionality “cache_files=” in the function “StreamingStep(” in order to distribute the 2 files (fileA and fileAC) to each of the clusters. It used to work for other scripts but here it doesn’t. Any thought ?

Here is the script:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))

def main(argv):

filenameAC = 'activities.log'
filenameA = 'activitiesCookieCountry.log'

fileC = fileinput.FileInput(sys.argv[1:])
fileA = open(filenameA,'r')
fileAC = open(filenameAC,'r')
fileA = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in fileA]
Alines = set(fileA)
for lineC in fileC:

fieldC = lineC.split('#')
fieldComp = fieldC[0]+'#'+fieldC[2] 
p = 0
if fieldComp in Alines:
fileAC.seek(0)
for lineAC in fileAC:
fieldAC = lineAC.split('#')
if (fieldAC[0] == fieldC[0]) and (fieldAC[2] == fieldC[2]) and (fieldAC[1] <             fieldC[1]):
p = 1
print('found')
if p == 0:
sys.stdout.write(lineC)

if __name__ == "__main__":
main(sys.argv)
```

And here is the script that runs the script within EMR:

```
utils = ['s3n://blablabla/activities.log#activities.log','s3n://blablabla/Activities/activitiesCookieCountry.log#activitiesCookieCountry.log']

sargs = ['-jobconf','mapred.output.compress=true','-jobconf','mapred.output.compression.type=block','-jobconf','mapred.compress.map.output=true','-jobconf','stream.map.output.field.separator="#"','-jobconf','mapred.reduce.tasks="1"']


cACstep = StreamingStep(
name='ClickActivityCheck',
mapper='s3n://blablabla/click-formatting-ACheck-S3.py',
reducer=None,
input='s3n://blablabla/ClickCleanedFeb14/*.gz',
output='s3n://blablabla/ClickCleaned2Feb14',
cache_files=utils,
step_args=sargs
)

jobid = conn.run_jobflow(
name= 'AWS_Flow_Test',
log_uri='s3n://blablabla/Logging/jobflow_logs',
ec2_keyname=’xxxx’,
availability_zone=None,
master_instance_type='m1.small',
slave_instance_type='m1.small',
num_instances=4,
action_on_failure=None,
keep_alive=False,
enable_debugging=True,
hadoop_version='1.0.3',
steps=[cACstep],
bootstrap_actions=[],
instance_groups=None,
additional_info=None,
ami_version='2.4.1',
api_params=None,
visible_to_all_users=True)
```

My suspicion is that the 2 files called shouldn’t be defined like this:

```
filenameAC = 'activities.log'
filenameA = 'activitiesCookieCountry.log'
```

But I don’t really know how else …